# Depending on fields' value (null or not) create new table with calculations only on not null values in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Let me try to explain what I want to do with this Access 2010 database.

I just want depending on the values inserted in table 1 to create the second table only with the rows that have values in table 1. So in the following example I want table 2 to just have 6 rows with calculations. I know I can make a code to hide the fields if the fields of table 1 are of null values but this requires a lot of work. I am really stuck here.
I don't want the data of table 2 to be stored. I just want them to be shown in forms and reports. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question in case somebody else is having the same needs.
So I used a UNION query and selected all the fields from table one while discarding all the NULL fields.

```
SELECT id,pososto_symmetoxis11 FROM systades WHERE pososto_symmetoxis11 Is Not Null; UNION SELECT id,pososto_symmetoxis12 FROM systades WHERE pososto_symmetoxis12 Is Not Null; UNION
```

So the 5x5 array became a table with 2 columns and the null fields went away.